# How to embed a library in a C program?

Tags: c

I would like to embed the lib tar library inside my program, so if I run it from another computer that doesn't have libtar installed it runs correctly. Also this eliminates version issues.

I still know little about C. Is it possible? What are the best practices?

Thank you very much.

Comment: It would probably help if you mention what OS and toolchain you are talking about, but in general you need static linking to include a library in your executable.

Comment: `Also this eliminates version issues.` Also, this introduces serious security issues. It's called static linking; somewhat relevant: [Why not bundle dependencies?](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Why_not_bundle_dependencies)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a static library and link your program with that library. That will embed the static library in your program so you won't need to have separately.

Comment: Great! I thought the linker was involved in some way. How can I do this? can you post sone examples, please? Thank you!!!

Comment: Quick google revealed these:  http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/cpp/gcc/create_lib.html http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/Building-a-library.html

Answer (score 2):

You have to link your app with a [static version of the library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_library#Creating_static_libraries_in_C.2FC.2B.2B) you're wanting to use.